# team city outputting db script

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, teamcity, database-project, teamcity-7.1

I am currently working with Team city to build my MVC application and used as my continous integration platform.

Within my solution I have an mvc project and a database project. Team city builds both and from the mvc project, a nuget package is created. As part of the database project, I have a build event that runs a powershell file that generates a database script.

Is it possible in the team city setup to output this script as part of its output and if so, how?

Comment: Not too familiar with TeamCity. Does it just use MSBuild or some command line to process the project? If just a command line, you could likely build/rebuild the project and add a SQLPackage command to generate the script. We usually do that and use Publish Profiles to point to the appropriate environment. That might also be possible with msbuild, though I haven't used msbuild to actually publish a SQL Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Teamcity Build Artifacts](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Artifact): you will find the generated script in the "Artifacts" tab at the end of the build run.